# Concatenate columns if they don't contain a zero

Tags: r, classification

Im trying to concatenate 4 [Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWwbP.png) into a single column named "tags" for later use of multilabel classification. I would like to concate the columns in a way that gives a an output only pasting columns that are not zero and thereto seperate them with a comma.
An example would be that the cell in last row would be {1,2} instead of {1,2,0,0}

I currently have no code that works as needed and haven't been able to find something on the internet. Do you guys have a tip to do this?

Current code:

```
df$TV[df$TV==1] = '1'
df$Internet[df$Internet ==1] = '2'
df$Mobil[df$Mobil==1] = '3'
df$Fastnet[df$Fastnet==1] = '4'
df$tags = paste(df$TV,df$Internet,df$Mobil,df$Fastnet,  sep=",")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base R option using `apply` -

```
cols <- c('TV', 'Internet', 'Mobil', 'Fastnet')
#df <- read.csv('stack.csv')
df$tags <- apply(df[cols], 1, function(x) toString(x[x!= 0]))
df
```

In `dplyr` we can use `rowwise` -

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(tags = {
    tmp <- c_across(all_of(cols))
    toString(tmp[tmp != 0])
  }) %>%
  ungroup

df
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for fast reponse - the base R option doesn't work for me. When I try the dplyr I get the following error "Error: `c_across()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs."

Comment: @Mads-EmilHvidRasmussen What do you mean by doesn't work? Does it give an error or gives an incorrect output ? Can you provide the data in a reproducible format so that it is easier to use it. We can't copy data from an image.

Comment: It gives wrong output. Here is a link to download a subset of dataframe I have https://www.filemail.com/d/dykpspfyklhzodl

Comment: When using the R base, it puts in the text string from the "text" column into the "tags" column.

Comment: @Mads-EmilHvidRasmussen Try the updated answer.

Comment: You are a champion! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

We may use `dapply` from `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
cols <- c('TV', 'Internet', 'Mobil', 'Fastnet')
df$tags <- dapply(slt(df, cols) MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) toString(x[x != 0]))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(TV = c(1, 3, 2, 0), Internet = c(1, 0, 1, 4), Mobil = c(0, 1, 3, 2), Fastnet = c(1, 5, 3, 2))
```